# cannot compile smslib example codes

Tags: java, ant, smslib

I seriously need help regarding this matter and I am really exhausted now, googled everything and finally made an account here. I am trying to send a message on mobile using smslib. I am done with the installation and placement of jar files. What I don't understand is when I try to compile a java program located in the smslib examples folder, It fails to recognize any class. I have *smslib-v3-master* folder, I work in the Notepad++ for compiling my programs.
I did the *ant commands* but nothing would help. I don't have any idea about the relationship of ant with build.xml and what actually happens, Please I need help here. Programs are not compiling because javac won't recognize class or interface

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Project
Place Jar and .dll Files to the relevent folder.
Copy the code located in SENDMesssage file located in \smslib-v3-master\src\java\examples\modem\
Change COM Port number and SMS Center Number.
Modify and use as your wish.